# How can I easily restrict all apps EXCEPT specific apps from using data?

Tags: permissions, data-monitoring

Let's say I have 100 apps on my Nexus 4.

I want to limit all but 2 of them from running on my data plan (I have 30MB a month).

- How can I easily exclude all apps *except* specific applications from using data (both fore/background)?

Comment: "Limit all except" means using a so-called "white-list". If your device is rooted, you might take a look at [DroidWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) and its forks [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) plus [Android Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jtschohl.androidfirewall), they support it. As shipped, with Android's native settings you can AFAIK only limit apps separately (black-list).